# Magento2- restoreQuote() 502 Bad Gateway for Guest users

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

When I'm trying to do purchase as a Guest user, 
Payment module calls `$this->checkoutSession->restoreQuote()`; while redirecting back to Magento store.

It will return `502` Bad gateway error only for guest users.

For registered users that works well.

Answer (score 1):

@prasad - have you verified your log files ( exception, support_report, access.log, php.access.log file ) ? I assume, its trying to process some code which may be related to logged in user.

Generally 502 Bad Gateway error may comes due to the process timeout.

Comment: Hi dude. Actually it occurs only for guest users. For registered users it works well.